# HTML-CSS a href text-align half left half right

Tags: html, css

I have this example code:

```
<li><a href="#"><em>&euro; 2,75</em> Koffie</a></li>
```

Witch I have to make like this the image.
"euro 2,75" right-aligned
"koffie" left-aligned
[image]

What I have tried so far css:

```
em {
float: right;
}
a {
float: left;
}
```

and

```
<li><a href="#"><em>&euro;<span style="float:right;"> 2,75</span></em> <span style="float:left;"> Koffie</span></a></li>
```

witch has to work on a normal line text but none of these works.
Is this even possible?

Comment: what part of that screenshot are you trying to replicate, and what is happening instead? unclear what precisely the issue is

Comment: Ow sorry for the haziness, I though it would be clear :P
the link above has the text "euro 2,75" & "koffie", witch I want like the image, so "euro 2,75" right-align and "koffie" left align

Comment: This might be one of the cases where using `<table>` would be justified.

Comment: It's absolutely the right place for a `table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
li {
    width: 200px;
}
.one {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.two {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#"><span class="one"><em>Koffie</em></span><span class="two">&euro; 2,75</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers - instead explain what you do and why. Also, is the `float` and `text-align` on `.one` necessary?

Comment: Hey Jim, By the way, Anders is correct that the float and text-align are most probably not necessary (depending on the rest of your code.) In fact, you could accomplish this without adding classes at all (again depending on the rest of your code.) Check out The :last-child and :first-child CSS pseudo-class when you get a chance.   You could even do it by using tables if you really really wanted to... but don't

Comment: Also if you leave the width out then it will still work but at the width of the inherited width so if you change it you won't need to change it twice.